# How to refer overriden static method from parent class constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

So we have some class (i.e. Button) and its method which takes void function.
Also we have parent class State which has static method buttonAction used to asign
to Button instance. Problem is State's child class must have an option to override
static method buttonAction and this method must be assigned to button by parent class State constructor.

It must work something like this:

Code:

```
MyState st;
button.click();
```

Desired output:

```
MyState::buttonAction!
```

But instead I get:

```
State::buttonAction!
```

Related .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

class Button
{
public:
    void setAction(void(*foo)(void));
    void click();
private:
    void(*foo)(void);
};

void Button::setAction(void(*foo)(void)) { this->foo = foo; }

void Button::click() { this->foo(); }

Button button;

class State
{
public:
    State();
private:
    static void buttonAction();
};

State::State()
{
    button.setAction(this->buttonAction); // pointer to state's buttonAction
}

void State::buttonAction()
{
    printf("State::buttonAction!");
};

class MyState : State
{
private:
    static void buttonAction(); // overridden buttonAction 
};

void MyState::buttonAction()
{
    printf("MyState::buttonAction!");
};

int main() {
    MyState st;
    button.click();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question fails to meet the requirement for providing a [mcve].

Comment: Edited code. Now it runs as described in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have MyState's constructor override it:

```
MyState::MyState()
{
    button.setAction(&buttonAction)l
}
```

After the superclass initially invokes `setAction()` to point the callback to its own static class function, this will override it, and repoint it to `MyState`'s static class function.

Comment: Is it possible without overriding constructor? Because I have more MyStates and buttonActions :)

Comment: It might be possible if instead of a plain function pointer, a `std::function` is used instead. But with a plain function pointer, the options are limited.